# Single loss function with multi-input multi-output model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train a multi-input (3) multi-output (4) model using Keras and I need to use a SINGLE loss function that takes in all the output predictions. 2 of these outputs are my true model outputs that I care about and have corresponding labels, while the other 2 outputs are learnable parameters from within my model that I want to use to dynamically update the loss weights for my true model outputs.
I need something like this:

`model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = unified_loss`

where the unified loss should have access to all my model outputs and corresponding labels. I am using `tf.data.from_tensor_slices(...)` to train.

The only workaround I have found is to use a custom training loop, which allows this. But, I lose a lot of functionality and callbacks become trickier to implement.

Is there a way to solve this using the regular `model.compilt(...)` and `model.fit(...)`?

Apart from a custom training loop, which is not preferred, I did try the standard approach of:

`model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = [loss1, loss2], loss_weights = [alpha, beta]`

where I tried to make alpha and beta learnable parameters but this is not desired because I have a custom equation that is more involved than a simple weighted sum.

Comment: When you design a custom loss function with definition `def custom_loss( y_pred , y_true )`, `y_pred` contains all output tensors of the model stored in a tuple. You can unpack those tensors and perform the weighed sum.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see, so something like what Yaoshiang mentioned. How will this work for y_true since I am using tf.data.from_tensor_slices(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a layer to your model that concats the losses into a single tensor/output. Have your custom loss parse out each of the four values and run the necessary math on them. During inference, run the model without the extra layer.

The pattern of having a slightly different model for training and inference is a common one.

Here is an example of the basic idea:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp1 = tf.keras.Input((1,))
inp2 = tf.keras.Input((1,))
inp3 = tf.keras.Input((1,))

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([inp1, inp2, inp3])
out1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
out2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
out3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
out4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)

model = tf.keras.Model([inp1, inp2, inp3], [out1, out2, out3, out4])

x1 = tf.convert_to_tensor([1])
x2 = tf.convert_to_tensor([1])
x3 = tf.convert_to_tensor([1])

model((x1, x2, x3))

outs = tf.stack([out1, out2, out3, out4])

training_model = tf.keras.Model([inp1, inp2, inp3], outs)

training_model((x1, x2, x3))

def exotic_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  true1, true2, true3 = tf.unstack(y_true)
  pred1, pred2, pred3 = tf.unstack(y_pred)
  return true1 + true2 + true3 + pred1 + pred2 + pred3

training_model.compile(loss=exotic_loss)
```

Comment: What about the case in which `out1`, `out2`, `out3` and `out4` have incompatible shapes?

Comment: Flatten to a vector then reshape to the original sizes.